# how can I do login form for angular?

Tags: html, angular, mongodb, express

I am trying to create a login form for my website. I'm using agular , express and mongoDB

Here's my controller of login function:

```
loginUser: (req, res) => {
    User.findOne({
            username: req.body.login_username
        })
        .then(user => {
            bcrypt.compare(req.body.login_password, user.password)
                .then(result => {
                    if (result) {
                        req.body.login_username = user.username
                        res.json({
                            message: "Success!",
                            added: true
                        });
                    } else {
                        console.log('Failed login attempt')
                        res.json({
                            message: "Error!",
                            error: err
                        });
                    }
                }).catch(console.error, console.log(req.body.login_password, user.password))
        })
}
```

and here is my login components:

```
  userID: string;
  userData: any;
  loginUser: any;
  error = "";

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private httpService: HttpService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.userID = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get("id");
    this.getSingleUser();
    this.loginUser = { username: "", password: "" };
  }

  getSingleUser() {
    let observable = this.httpService.getOneUser(this.userID);
    observable.subscribe((data) => {
      this.userData = data;
    });
  }
  onSubmit() {
    let observable = this.httpService.loginUser(this.loginUser);
    observable.subscribe((data: any) => {
      console.log("Wrong");
      if (data.error) {
        this.error = data.error.errors.name.message;
      } else {
        this.getSingleUser();
        this.router.navigate([""]);
      }
    });
  }
```

When I click on button my terminal getting an error like this:

> undefined $2b$20$8DmOjsDm3h5q/jEq9lNauezUdFYdL6EBt9gjmCu8/0DU0kAnSSIA2
>   Error: data and hash arguments required
>       at Object.compare (/Users/nhannguyen/Desktop/personal_project/instagram/node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js:208:17)
>       at /Users/nhannguyen/Desktop/personal_project/instagram/node_modules/bcrypt/promises.js:29:12
>       at new Promise ()
>       at Object.module.exports.promise (/Users/nhannguyen/Desktop/personal_project/instagram/node_modules/bcrypt/promises.js:20:12)
>       at Object.compare (/Users/nhannguyen/Desktop/personal_project/instagram/node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js:204:25)
>       at /Users/nhannguyen/Desktop/personal_project/instagram/server/controllers/users.js:65:24
>       at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)

Comment: So have you tried passing `{ useUnifiedTopology: true }` to MongoClient constructor? Your error states that you are using deprecated stuff

Comment: Im guessing either req.body.login_password or user.password is empty..

Please add .catch(console.error) after the .then() to see the error

Comment: I have not use ```{ useUnifiedTopology: true }``` let me google how it works!

Comment: yes @DutchKevv thats the whole error

Comment: Please add .catch(console.error) after the .then() to see the error. I personally don't think the deprecation warning has anything to do with it

Comment: @DutchKevv just updated my error and added console.error! May you take a look for me! Thanks alot

Comment: Roger.. Its missing at least one field so it seems. Have you tried console.log(req.body.login_password, user.password) to double check if they are not empty?

Comment: @DutchKevv got it! It got my ```req.body.password``` but seem like it didnt get ```req.body.login_password``` i just updated my error

Comment: Have you checked in the chrome network panel if the value is really send to the server??
Also, have you installed + applied the app.use(bodyParser.json()) of the body-parser plugin for express? Otherwise the body is not read by the server

https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html

Comment: hey @DutchKevv Thanks alot. Thanks for show me how to console errors. I fixed it! Really appreciate man.

Comment: No worries :) Can you set the post below as answer so I get some points for it and others users can read it? Thanks

Comment: @DutchKevv gotcha. Thanks fam i dont have 15 reputation so i couldnt set the upvote for you sorry!

Comment: Haha no worries, i started a new account on SO so i'm back to almost zero also :p I upvoted your question so you got some extra points :) Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add .catch(console.error) after the .then() to catch the full error.

After that check if the values are really there and if not, check if the body-parser plugin is installed